# How to update pivot data without clearing PivotTable Fields on Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My current code seems to be updating the source data range, but it is clearing the fields and filters. Is there any way to avoid that?

```
sub update_pivot()

'change data range for pivot
   Dim EndRow As Integer
   Dim DataRange As Range
   Dim NewRange As String
   Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
   Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet


   Set Data_Sheet = Workbooks(myfile).Worksheets("Consolidation")
   Set Pivot_Sheet = Workbooks(myfile).Worksheets("Consolidation Pivot")


' find the last row in my data sheet
   Data_Sheet.Select    
   EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$I" & EndRow)
   NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

   Pivot_Sheet.Select
   Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6"). _
   ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
   PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)

' Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
   Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Comment: Works OK for me, as long as the field names don't change.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it's necessary to add the preferred fields and filters. I believe the settings is stored within the .PivotCache, where changing cache will not have any fields or filters predetermined.

My solution would be to end the macro off with:

```
With Pivot_Sheet("PivotTable6")
   .AddDataField .PivotFields("VariableName1")
   .AddRowFields:=Array("VariableName2")
   .RefreshTable
End with
```